# How to refer to a cell value when using a query

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I am trying to populate columns `C,D,E,L,K,M,N` on a Google Sheets spreadsheet..

Below is my code but it returned a VALUE error when I ran it. Could someone please advice?

```
=QUERY(QUERY('BI_Keywords Raw Data'!$A:$C, "Select * WHERE B = """&B2&""" " ), "SELECT * OFFSET 1", 0)
```

[image]

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you tried this BigQuery Connector to see if it fits your need? https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/g-suite/connecting-bigquery-and-google-sheets-to-help-with-hefty-data-analysis

Comment: I see nothing related to BigQuery here. `QUERY()` is an internal google sheets thing. https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en (hence I removed the tag)

Comment: @FelipeHoffa Quite right. Nothing to do with BigQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a **mistake within the query syntax** trying to connect it with the value in cell `C2`.

**To include a cell value in a query you need to use a combination of singe and double quotes** like

```
'"&A8&"'
```

*Single quote `'` double quote `"` ampersand `&` cell `A8` ampersand `&`double quote `"` single quote `'`*

Thus, your corrected query would be

```
=QUERY(QUERY('BI_Keywords Raw Data'!$A:$C, "Select * WHERE B = ' "&B2&" ' " ), "SELECT * OFFSET 1", 0)
```